# Cannot access external service in Kubernetes AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have already made a Kubernetes 1.5 cluster which is running in AWS using KOPS. I have many nodes in there with various instance type such as t2.medium, m3.medium, c4.large and c4.xlarge. But sometimes my Kubernetes pods running on t2.medium, m3.medium, c4.large cannot access external service like Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS), Elasticsearch and external SMS service. For RDS i got an error message PG::ConnectionBad and for others i got timeout. Does the problem come from AWS node instance or from Kubernetes pods? Because i never get an error if using c4.xlarge and up. If the problem come from my AWS instance, why that happened?

Thank you

Comment: Are your services (RDS, ES) in the same VPC? 
What about the ACL and Security Groups...

Comment: Yes, but only RDS are using the same VPC, ACL , Security Groups and Subnet. For ES, i use AWS Elasticsearch Service and the configurations can't be set manually

Comment: We need more date. What happens when you are trying to access AWS resources like RDS from node OS, not from within pod?

Comment: This is a vague question with little supporting details. What does "sometimes" mean? Do you intermittently connect to external services successfully, and other times they fail without any configuration changes? What do your ingress/egress rules look like for the relevant security groups? Are you using an ExternalName service to connect to them?